# Querying JSONB. Sequelize Op.In throws Error: Invalid value

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a postgresql JSONB field named "config".

Example of a value in the field "config"

```
{ 
   "rewards":{ 
      "policyA":[ 
         { 
            "enforcedDate":"some-date",
            "anotherKey":"some-val"
         },
         { 
            "enforcedDate":"some-date-2",
            "anotherKey":"some-val-2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's what I've tried. I am trying to find all records that has an enforcedDate of "some-date" as such.

```
MyEntity.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    config: {
      rewards: {
        policyA: [ { enforcedDate: "some-date" } ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Or

```
MyEntity.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    config: {
      rewards: {
        policyA: {
          [Op.in]: [ { enforcedDate: "some-date" } ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Error I am getting

```
Invalid value { enforcedDate: 'some-date' }

      at escape (node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:65:11)
      at Object.partialEscape [as escape] (node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:57:37)
      at ABSTRACT.<anonymous> (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:469:22)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ABSTRACT._value (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:458:19)
      at ABSTRACT._stringify (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/data-types.js:473:29)
      at ABSTRACT.stringify (node_modules/sequelize/lib/data-types.js:23:19)
      at Object.escape (node_modules/sequelize/lib/sql-string.js:59:40)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator.escape (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:986:22)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereParseSingleValueObject (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2556:41)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator.whereItemQuery (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2272:21)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator._traverseJSON (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2392:21)
      at node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2385:14
      at node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
      at baseForOwn (node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
      at Function.forOwn (node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13014:24)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator._traverseJSON (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2384:9)
      at node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2361:12
      at node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
      at baseForOwn (node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
      at Function.forOwn (node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13014:24)
      at PostgresQueryGenerator._whereJSON (node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:2360:7)
```

Seems to be similar to [Sequelize Op.contains throws Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370932/sequelize-op-contains-throws-unhandled-rejection-error-invalid-value)

Which has no answer to it.

Raw sql query like the 1 below works fine

```
 select *
    FROM "MyEntity"
    where config @> '{"rewards": {"policyA": [{"enforcedDate": "some-date"}]}}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Op.contains](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/801aa3658199bd8fa706447d4b62c6eb7f1a4d46/types/lib/operators.d.ts#L112), e.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes, Op } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

class MyEntity extends Model {}
MyEntity.init(
  {
    config: DataTypes.JSONB,
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'MyEntity' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    await MyEntity.create({
      config: {
        rewards: {
          policyA: [
            { enforcedDate: 'some-date', anotherKey: 'some-val' },
            { enforcedDate: 'some-date-2', anotherKey: 'some-val-2' },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    const rval = await MyEntity.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        config: {
          [Op.contains]: {
            rewards: {
              policyA: [{ enforcedDate: 'some-date' }],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    assert(rval.count === 1, 'The count of entities should be equal 1');
    console.log('entity.config:', rval.rows[0]['config']);
    const rval2 = await MyEntity.findAndCountAll({
      where: {
        config: {
          [Op.contains]: {
            rewards: {
              policyA: [{ enforcedDate: 'some' }],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    assert(rval2.count === 0, 'The count of entities should be 0');
    console.log('rval2:', rval2);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

Data rows of `MyEntity` table in database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "MyEntity";
 id |                                                                      config
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"rewards": {"policyA": [{"anotherKey": "some-val", "enforcedDate": "some-date"}, {"anotherKey": "some-val-2", "enforcedDate": "some-date-2"}]}}
(1 row)
```

The result logs after executing the code:

```js
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MyEntity" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "MyEntity" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "MyEntity" ("id"   SERIAL , "config" JSONB, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'MyEntity' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "MyEntity" ("id","config") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "MyEntity" AS "MyEntity" WHERE "MyEntity"."config" @> '{"rewards":{"policyA":[{"enforcedDate":"some-date"}]}}';
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "config" FROM "MyEntity" AS "MyEntity" WHERE "MyEntity"."config" @> '{"rewards":{"policyA":[{"enforcedDate":"some-date"}]}}';
entity.config: { rewards: { policyA: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
Executing (default): SELECT count(*) AS "count" FROM "MyEntity" AS "MyEntity" WHERE "MyEntity"."config" @> '{"rewards":{"policyA":[{"enforcedDate":"some"}]}}';
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "config" FROM "MyEntity" AS "MyEntity" WHERE "MyEntity"."config" @> '{"rewards":{"policyA":[{"enforcedDate":"some"}]}}';
rval2: { count: 0, rows: [] }
```