# Use where clause with or condition in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use or condition in sequelize to represent a query for example like,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title = "title" OR genre = "genre"
```

however, this is what I have already tried

```
const checkTitle= await User.findOne({
        where: {
            $or: [
                { title: req.body.title },
                { genre: req.body.genre }
            ]
        }
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

but it keeps giving me an error which says invalid value

```
Invalid value { title: 'title' }
```

I wonder how to properly use OR condition in sequelize?

Comment: What Sequelize version are you using?

Comment: I'm using sequelize version 6.3.4

Comment: Thank you for your concern, I have already found the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51370932/sequelize-op-contains-throws-unhandled-rejection-error-invalid-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the curly bracket after title and genre in your code.
The code should like this:

```
const checkTitle= await User.findOne({
        where: {
            $or: [
                 title: {req.body.title },
                 genre: {req.body.genre }
            ]
        }
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

The syntax for logical operations is modified in the latest version of sequelize. For

**Sequelize >= 4.12**

```
const checkTitle= await User.findOne({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                title: {req.body.title },
                description: {req.body.genre }
            ]
        }
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: yes, I changed the $or with [Op.or] and it worked, thank you!